# VirtualBox doesn't have Devices menu

Tags: 11.10, virtualbox

I want to install "Guest Addition" for my virtual Windows 7 but I don't see Devices menu. Why?
[image]

Answer (score 17):

I faced the same issue. You need to exit from scale mode (Right Ctrl + C). Then 'Devices' menu will appear.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I was going crazy.

Comment: Thanks from me as well, I was also very confused as to why I did not see it.

Answer (score 10):

The ***Devices***-menu to install [Guest Additions](https://askubuntu.com/a/22745/3940) will only be available **after** the virtual machine was started, is running, and the guest windows has focus.

Comment: There is no Devices menu even I start the Win7 machine, so I asked this question here.

Comment: The screenshot you included does **not** show any VM running. In fact it shows the menu from VBox Manager and **not** the menu you get when a running virtual guest windows has focus. That's why I felt you may need this answer. If I am wrong here then please edit your question to clarify this important detail.

Comment: what does it mean - "the guest windows has focus"?

Answer (score 7):

You can activate 'Devices' menu via View -> Menu Bar -> Menu Bar Settings.

Comment: This exactly! My menu bar simply wasn't showing that option.

Comment: YOU MY FRIEND, ARE MY SAVIOR. I don't think I deactivated it, so...

Answer (score 6):

Did you install the OSE from the repositories? The Guest Addons are proprietary and are not included in the OSE version of VB. You can [download the guest addons ISO separately](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/) and install them that way.

Comment: This is not so. Only the Oracle extensions needed for RDP and USB2.0 support are closed source. Guest Additions are also included in the OSE edition. See also http://askubuntu.com/a/22745/3940

Comment: As for Guest Additions there is a transitional package **virtualbox-ose-guest-utils** for the OSE edition in the repositories.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue with MAC host and Ubuntu guest.
Finally, I found this:

1. Go to preferences.
2. Select **input → Virtual Machine**
3. Add shortcut key to **Menu Bar Settings**  (I added HOST key + M)

   [image: VirtualBox - Input dialog]
4. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> and go to running virtual machine and press the key combination for Menu Bar Settings. Then you can see the menu at the top of the screen

   [image: dropdown menus in window]

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Can you explain to us how this strategy will cause the Devices menu to appear? (or did you misunderstand the question)

Comment: @ElderGeek, Thanks! Sorry, I did not understand this in your comment "did you misunderstand the question". I just did this to enable "Device Menu" of running virtual machine.

Comment: If that is indeed the case please [edit] your question to explain how your approach enables the Device Menu in Virtualbox running on Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to activate the shared folders.

It's easy:

1. Start your virtual machine
2. Select "Mount CD/DVD-ROM" from the "Devices" menu in the virtual machine's menu bar and then "CD/DVD-ROM image".
3. In the Virtual Media Manager, press the "Add" button and browse your host file system for the VBoxGuestAdditions.iso file: 
   On a Linux host, you can find this file in the additions folder under where you installed VirtualBox (normally /opt/VirtualBox/). to me: "/usr/share/virtualbox/"
4. Back in the Virtual Media Manager, select that ISO file and press the "Select" button. This will mount the ISO file and present it to your Windows guest as a CD-ROM.
5. Now open My PC from Windows
6. There open de CD/DVD mounted: "VirtualBox Guest Additions"
7. Open "VBoxWindowsAdditions-.exe", my pc is 32x so open: VBoxWindowsAdditions-x86.exe, if you need rights click Yes.
8. click next
9. click next or change the path
10. Select Direct 3D support (optional) and Click Install
11. Wait and click Finish and reboot your virtual machine

Comment: There is no Devices menu

Answer (score 1):

Just go to user interface in Machine settings and mark devices so devices background become gray then restart your Machine and you will see Devices on the Menu bar.

Works for all options you need to see on Menu bar.

[image]

Comment: This answer worked for me eventually but this may help find the checkbox you need in VirtualBox 6.1:

-Open Oracle VM VirtualBox 6.1 Manager
-Select your machine
-Settings
-User Interface
-Click on Devices button
-Show at Top of Screen
-OK
-Start

Answer (score 0):

This works if your host machine is Ubuntu 11.10:-

When your virtual machine is running and is the active/focused window.  Look to the top left of your screen, it should show "VirtualBox".

Move your mouse over the x in "VirtualBox", then you should see the Devices menu.

Comment: Looking at the image shows that this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

On the guest machine monitor right click on the menu bar. Select Menu Bar Settings. Only the options that are there in your menu bar will be highlighted. You would find Devices option un-highlighted.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZ2s5.png).

Select it and press the green check button at the right end of the bar. The devices option should appear. This worked for me in VirtualBox version 5.1.26.

Comment: This doesnt' work in gnome. there is no menu bar settings